# Add function via decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Is there a valid way to add a function via a decorator?

Decorator:

```
function testDecorator(options){
    return function(target){
        target.test = function() {
            console.log('Zipp Zapp!');
        };
    }
}
```

Class:

```
@testDecorator({})
class Book{

}
```

Usage (preferred in this case) like

```
Book.test()
```

typescript compilation results in:

`Property 'test' does not exist on type 'typeof Book'.`

Usage like

```
var b = new Book();
b.test();
```

typescript compilation results in:

`Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Book'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `Book` class/instance doesn't have a definition for this `test` function.

You can do this for the `Book.test` version:

```
function testDecorator(options) {
    return function(target) {
        target.test = function() {
            console.log('Zipp Zapp!');
        };
    }
}

interface BookConstructor {
    new (): Book;
    test(): void;
}

@testDecorator({})
class Book {}

(Book as BookConstructor).test();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testDecorator(options)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function(target)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.test%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Zipp%20Zapp!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BookConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%09new%20()%3A%20Book%3B%0D%0A%09test()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40testDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20Book%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A(Book%20as%20BookConstructor).test()%3B))

Or this for the `new Book().test` version:

```
function testDecorator(options) {
    return function(target) {
        target.prototype.test = function() {
            console.log('Zipp Zapp!');
        };
    }
}

interface Testable {
    test(): void;
}

@testDecorator({})
class Book {}

let b = new Book();
(b as Testable).test();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testDecorator(options)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function(target)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.prototype.test%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Zipp%20Zapp!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Testable%20%7B%0D%0A%09test()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40testDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20Book%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20Book()%3B%0D%0A(b%20as%20Testable).test()%3B))

The main difference here is that we're doing:

```
target.prototype.test = function() { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
target.test = function() { ... }
```

In both cases you'll need to cast because the Book object/class doesn't declare the instance/static method `test` but it's being added by the decorator.